# echo post-permalink without http and www

Tags: permalinks, urls, customization

I have this line …

```
<div class="permalink"><?php the_permalink(); ?></div>
```

and the result on my page looks like this …

```
http://mysite.com/whatever/post-or-so
```

I guess it could also look like this …

```
http://www.mysite.com/whatever/post-or-so
```

However I'd like to have just `mysite.com/whatever/post-or-so` without the `http://` or `www` in front of it.

What is the best and easiest way to do so?

Don't get me wrong, this has nothing todo with rewriting permalinks or whatsoever. Just a simple echo of `the_permalink()` on my page that is not handled as link but as normal text. And in this case I would like to get rid of the http or www.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`get_permalink`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) instead of `the_permalink` and manipulate it however you'd like via php.

Answer (score 6):

Like @milo suggested you can manipulate the return of [`get_permalink()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink). This can easily be done via several php [string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php), here in use is [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). If you have the need to remove both `http://` and `https://` give an array of needles to `str_replace()`.

```
$permalink = get_permalink();
$find = array( 'http://', 'https://' );
$replace = '';
$output = str_replace( $find, $replace, $permalink );
echo '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
```

The above isn't taking care of the `www(.)` part, but the principle should be clear.

Another possibility for manipulation are php [PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php), here used [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$permalink = get_permalink();
$find_h = '#^http(s)?://#';
$find_w = '/^www\./';
$replace = '';
$output = preg_replace( $find_h, $replace, $permalink );
$output = preg_replace( $find_w, $replace, $output );
echo '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple method.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will return the absolute url without http(s) in the beginning.

Comment: Only of the current page. This won't work for showing links to other pages in the loop, like get_permalink will.